# Disable lock Screen in Android 21 and above

Tags: android, lockscreen, keyguard

I am trying to disable lock screen while making my screen turn off but as soon as screen turns off lock is held again.

I am using below code to disable the lock screen:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
} else {
    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) activity.getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    kl = km.newKeyguardLock("name");
    kl.disableKeyguard();
}
```

And to enable the lock screen:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
} else {
    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) activity.getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    kl = km.newKeyguardLock("name");
    kl.reenableKeyguard();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in OnCreate of the Activity.

```
 Window win = getWindow();
    win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED will only show my screen when device is locked but wont prevent it from locking. and if I use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON it always wake up my screen.

Answer (score 0):

Please give below **permission also in android.manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

You can also refer this link for more info

https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/